# On Node.js can I send a request and close it before the answer?

Tags: node.js, request, httprequest

I understand the usual HTTP request life cycle, what I would like to do is:

Make a request to an endpoint, when all data has been sent, I'd like to close the connection right away, ignoring any possible answer.

Notice that I don't want to just ignore the answer, I want to literally not listen for one, because the connection would be closed =)

Comment: Note that, depending on the endpoint and how it behaves, there's no guarantee that your request would complete if the client disconnected before receiving a response.

Comment: What you want is to simply ignore and not wait for a response... see my answer below... you can just have the client's response from the other server .resume() which will let the response run ithout waiting for the result.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't wire up the client data event.

```
app.post('/something', function(req,res) {
   client.post(...., function(res2){
       //let the posted value and response finish
       //won't do anything with it
       res2.resume(); 

       //if you want to return after post, but before response data is read.
       //comment out the res.end below, and use this one.
       // res.end("done");
   });

   //if you are just wanting to fire and forget the post request...
   res.end("done");
});
```

Comment: Note: if you are wanting to limit the outbound connections, you may want to wrap your client inside a generic pool...